# 12 voltage LED Strip

Tags: voltage, led, high-voltage, led-strip

If I buy red led strip which wants 12 volts of electricity as input to glow.  So I can't directly plug into wall socket (India) which is 220 to 250 voltage AC current. So which components(like for example step down transformer, resistor , etc ) should I put in between led strip and my wall socket so that it supplies 12 volts as the output from that components to the led strip.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a 12volt dc adapter which converts your 220v ac to 12v dc supply. Buy one that can supply ample current to the LEDs. A 3Amp supply works great. DO NOT connect them directly to the mains. It'll potentially blowup which could cause physical injury.

Judging by your question, you don't have much knowledge in this field. So, I would suggest you consult with your local electrician.

Answer (score 0):

You need a power supply that outputs 12VDC. The 12V led strip has the current limiting resistors included. Low cost power supplies often have a difficult output connector to use freely, but if you can connect the leds strip, then you likely can handle the DC cord, too. Consult with a local professional electrician to be sure of the polarity and all safety details. Don't skip this! It's your life and your home!

Power supplies have different maximum allowed output currents. How much current you need, it depends on the spec mA/meter of your leds and on how long is your strip.  Leave 25...50% safety margin due the tolerances. Also it's no good tu push a power supply to the limit, because it easily gets hot. It's max. output current is specified in free air.  Leave also some room for expansion, if you even slightly think it will be needed.

In theory it's possible to drive the leds directly from an 12VAC output transformer, maybe having only a full-wave rectifier. Forget it. They blink intolerably.

If you need dimming, buy a high frequency PWM dimmer. Do not try to install a resistor. It gets easily hot if not properly calculated.